# How to multiboot 2 Android-X86 distro? (for instance PrimeOS and Bliss OS)

Tags: boot, android-x86

How to multiboot 2 Android-X86 distro?

I tried to make a dual boot with Bliss OS and PrimeOS.

I installed Bliss OS to its dedicated partition on my hard drive.
It was perfectly booting and working.
Then, I installed PrimeOS.
It was perfectly booting, but it changed the GRUB config and made it only possible to boot Prime.

I reinstalled Bliss OS, same thing.

I edited the GRUB config files, as mentioned here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492587/add-prime-os-android-x86-x64-to-grub-menu/519867?noredirect=1#comment1090351_519867

It seems only one of the occurrence of an Android-X86 ISO is able to boot in a given system.
How to fix the config file to boot several of them?

Answer (score 0):

The way android_x86 treats EFI GRUB config is buggy or misunderstood. No matter what android_installation you choose from grub it will just boot the first found android system on the hard drive (and it seems that device.map that causes the pain).

Anyhow here is a workaround that I did to get stuff working:

I wiped 1 of my laptops for that (MacBook Pro 8,1 320GB hard drive)

- Installed Linux (Kubuntu) choosing the whole hard drive as one part + efi

  ```
  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
  ├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
  └─sda2   8:2    0 297.6G  0 part /
  ```
- Installed PrimeOS choosing sda2 (DO NOT FORMAT), 
  ignore EFI installation (optional)
- Booted into Linux again and renamed primeOS installation folder

  ```
  sudo mv /android /primeOS
  ```
- Installed Bliss OS the same way as PrimeOS + choose /system to be rw
- Booted into Linux again, renamed Bliss OS installation folder

  ```
  sudo mv /blissos_x86.xx.xx /blissOS
  ```
- While still on Linux added both Android installations to GRUB by adding the following lines to `/etc/grube.d/40_custom`

  ```
  submenu 'Android' {                                                                                                                                              
      menuentry 'primeOS' --class android  --class android-x86_64 --class gnu-linux --class os {                                                                     
          set root='hd0,gpt2'                                                                                                                                        
          linux /primeOS/kernel root=/dev/ram0 SERIAL=random logo.showlogo=1 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet DATA= USB_DATA_PARTITION=1
          initrd /primeOS/initrd.img
      }
      menuentry 'blissOS' --class android  --class android-x86_64 --class gnu-linux --class os {
          set root='hd0,gpt2'
          linux /blissOS/kernel root=/dev/ram0 SERIAL=random logo.showlogo=1 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet DATA= USB_DATA_PARTITION=1
          initrd /blissOS/initrd.img
      }
  }
  ```
- Updated GRUB on Linux `sudo update-grub`, and made sure the tail of `/boot/grub/grub.conf` contains the Android entries
- Rebooted and chose one of the Android installations and I meet an error telling me `hd0,gpt2 not found` bizarre o.O ,  after a bit of googling it says that it happens when running grub-install before generating or coping device.map to /boot/grub!
  **To fix that I had to go back to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and change** `hd0 to hd1` in my case

**NOTE** for small hard drives like mine it's better to use one partition (ext4) shared between Linux and Androids, from all systems you enjoy the full free space.